# What are all the pieces to an effective TDD strategy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara

I'm really getting frustrated with learning how to properly develop software using TDD.  It seems that everyone does it differently and in a different order.  At this point, I'd just like to know what are all the considerations? This much is what I've come up with: I should use rspec, and capybara.  With that said, what are all the different types of test I need to write, to have a well built and tested application.  I'm looking for a list that comprises the area of my application being tested, the framework needed to test it, and any dependencies.

For example, it seems that people advise to start by unit testing your models, but when I watch tutorials on TDD it seems like they only write integration test.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the theme "how do you TDD" is as much out there in the open as the theme "how do you properly test?". In Ruby, and more specifically in Rails, rspec should be the tool to start with, but not be done with. RSpec allows you to write Unit Tests for your components, to test them separately. In the Rails context, that means:

- test your models
- test your controllers
- test your views
- test your helpers
- test your routes

It is a very good tool not exactly rails-bound, it is also used to test other frameworks.

After you're done with RSpec, you should jump to cucumber. Cucumber (http://cukes.info/) is the most used tool (again, for the Rails environment) to write integration tests. You can then integrate capybara on cucumber.

After you're done with cucumber, you'll be done with having tested your application backend and (part of) its HTML output. That's when you should also test your javascript code. How to do that? First, you'll have to Unit test it. Jasmine (http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) is one of the tools you might use for the job.

Then you'll have to test its integration in your structure. How to do that? You'll come back to cucumber and integrate selenium (http://seleniumhq.org/) with your cucumber framework, and you'll be able to test your integration "live" in the browser, having access to your javascript magic and testing it on the spot.

So, after you're done with these steps, you'll have covered most of the necessary steps to have a well-integrated test environment. Are we done? Not really. You should also set a coverage tool (one available: https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) to check if your code is being really well tested and no loose ends are left.

After you're done with these morose steps, you should also do one last thing, in case you are not developing it all alone and the team is big enough to make it still unmanageable by itself: you'll set a test server, which will do nothing other than run all the previous steps regularly and deliver notifications about its results.

So, all of this sets a good TDD environment for the interested developer. I only named the most used frameworks in the ruby/rails community for the different types of testing, but that doesn't mean there aren't other frameworks as or more suitable for your job. It still doesn't teach you how to test properly. For that there's more theory involved, and a lot of subdebates.

In case I forgot something, please write it in a comment below.

Besides that, you should approach how you test properly. Namely, are you going for the declarative or imperative approach?

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! Doesn't rspec offer integration test too? I see a lot of tutorials use rspec and capybara together to write integration test. So does cucumber/capybara do the same thing as rspec/capybara, and if so, what the the benefit of switching from using rspec for unit testing to cucumber for integration test?  Thanks again for the robust response!

Comment: depends what you perceive as integration. Rspec does offer you the possibility to test your end HTML structure result. Where it differs is in the type of testing you're doing. In Cucumber you create scenarios, in which a user is taken from A to B in your platform, it's more of a stakeholder thing. A good way to differ: whereas in cucumber you'd have a step called "and I fill up the signup form", in rspec you'd test exactly what it means to fill up the sign up form (insert name, choose country, etc...). But there is very good documentation about the differences between frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Start simple and add more tools and techniques as you need them.  There are many way to TDD an app because every app is different.  One way to do that is to start with an end-to-end test with Rspec and Capybara (or Cucumber and Capybara) and then add more fine-grained tests as you need them.

You know you need more fine-grained tests when it takes more than a few minutes to make a Capybara test pass.

Also, if the domain of your application is non-trivial it might be more fruitful for you to start testing the domain first.

It depends! Try different approaches and see what works for you.

Comment: what exactly does end-to-end entail? is that integration test first method?

Comment: You write a test that simulates what a user would do in the browser, and analyzes what the user then sees in the browser.

Comment: I'm almost there(forgive me)... but this is done through a rspec integration test, yes?

Comment: Yes, that would be my preferred way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

End-to-end development of real-world applications with TDD is an underdocumented activity indeed. It's true that you'll mostly find schoolbook examples, katas and theoretical articles out there. However, a few books take a more comprehensive and practical approach to TDD - [GOOS](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/) for instance (highly recommended), and, to a lesser extent, Beck's [Test Driven Development by Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530), although they don't address RoR specifically.

The approach described in GOOS starts with writing end-to-end acceptance tests (*integration* tests, which may amount to RSpec tests in your case) but within that loop, you code as many TDD *unit* tests as you need to design your lower-level objects. When writing those you can basically start where you want -from the outer layers, the inner layers or just the parts of your application that are most convenient to you. As long as you mock out any dependency, they'll remain unit tests anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same question when I started learning rails, there're so many tools or methods to make the test better but after spending to much time on that, I finally realized that you could simply forget the rule that you must do something or not, test something that you think it might have problem first, then somewhere else. Well ,it needs time.

that's just my point of view.